# unable to send email to myself from my server through gmail

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, gmail

I am unable to send email to myself from my server through gmail.

For example:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->to('me@gmail.com');
$this->email->from('me@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject('Try this');
$this->email->message('It worked'. date('h:i:sa'));
$this->email->send();
```

I use gmail with my domain name. So I am sending to me@mydomain.com actually but to be more clear I am using me@gmail.com as my example. If I set up the email->to variable with another email acount all works. I am able to mail out to all my customers with no problem.  I recieve mail from clients just fine to gmail.

I checked gmail spam filters and they are empty.  Blocked ip's are empty too.
Port 25 is open in my firewall and router.

I do not see errors.  On the server side, I see this instead from email debugging:

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail<br /><pre>User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 12 Oct 2015 13:27:11 -0700
From: &quot;Me&quot; &lt;me@gmail.com&gt;
Return-Path: &lt;me@gmail.com&gt;
Reply-To: &quot;me@gmail.com&quot; &lt;me@gmail.com&gt;
X-Sender: me@gmail.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: &lt;561c179fe94dd@gmail.com&gt;
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Try_this?=
It worked01:27:11pm
```

The email does not show up in my gmail in-box however.  Neither does it show up in the out box.  Is this a gmail issue? Is this a problem with how I have my DNS set up?

What am I missing?

Comment: Spam folder perhaps ?

Comment: Thanks Padro. No. it is not in the spam folder and the spam filters are empty.

Comment: Looking at my email log I get: Message ID 561c179fe94dd@gmail.com| Date 2015-10-12| Time 13:27:12| Sender me@gamil.com| Recipient me@gmail.com| Mail Size 0.5KB| Status Received|  So, it appears that it received some message from gmail that it was received.  I suspect this is a gmail issue and DNS must be fine.

Comment: Also, if I mail my self from the gmail directly it shows up in the in box.  This is only if I email my self from the server.

Comment: Can you edit your question with your config's that you use for email I only see `$config['mailtype'] = 'text';`

Comment: Yes, that is all I am using for this test email to keep it simple.  And like I say.  It works fine if I change email->to to another address.

Answer (score 0):

## With Codeigniter [Mail Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html)

```
$this->load->library('email'); //load Codeigniter E-Mailer Library

$this->email->from('test@gmail.com', 'Testing Bot');
$this->email->to('me@gmail.com'); 

//$this->email->cc('another@another-example.com'); 
//$this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com'); 

$this->email->subject('this is subject mail');

$message = 'this is Message'. date('h:i:s');
$this->email->message($message);    

if(!$this->email->send())
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
else
{
    echo 'Mail Sent'
}
```

## Using [phpMailer](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPMailer)

in `application/library`

Place `Emailer.php`

and in contrroller

```
$this->load->library('emailer');

$mail = new Emailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "";       

$msg = "this is Message". date('h:i:s');//youe message line one
$msg .= "Im Here tooo";//your message line two

$mail->AddAddress('me@gmail.com', 'My Name');
$mail->SetFrom('test@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo('test@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'this is subject mail';
$mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

if($mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Mail Sent';
}
else
{
    echo 'Failed';
}
```